# QuickBooks API V3 customerquery

Tags: vb.net, intuit-partner-platform

Does V3 handle a customerquery by displayname? For now I know I can do a service call with findbyid() but I would like to do a customerquery by the displayname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is supported.

Query - select * from Customer where DisplayName='John Doe'

Ref Customer Entity Doc - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer

DevkitRef - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/query_filters

You can try this call using ApiExplorer.
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

Thanks